# No artifacts found that match the file pattern - what file were it looking for?

Tags: jenkins

A common software idiocy: Jenkins

1. Accepts the path I gave it after validating it.
2. It would not accept any other path.
3. It doesn't even print what file it didn't find.

Why can't it print what path it didn't find? It's so useless to tell me back the bit of the path I asked it to archive... I cannot imagine anyone can be this... well, not smart to fail so much at basic usability...

Well, sorry for the rant. So, how do I find why did Jenkins fail to archive the file?

More details:

Build script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash -e
rm -rf ./sdk > /dev/null 2>&1
echo "started from $PWD"
echo "changed to $1"
cd "$(cygpath "$1")"
git clone ssh://********/sdk
cd ./sdk
git checkout -b preliminary
git pull origin preliminary
scons
cd ..
echo "back to $PWD"
```

How it is invoked:

```
d:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i /home/wvxvw/projects/sdk/jenkins-build "%WORKSPACE%"
```

The archiving instruction:

```
sdk/deploy/integration
```

This directory absolutely certainly exists.

PS. If I remove the archiving step, navigate to the workspace through the web interface, then download the zip archive of the entire build - the files I want to archive are there.

Comment: Since Jenkins accepts wildcards for archiving artifacts, it can't possibly print out all the possibilities that it didn't find. What exactly did you enter?

Comment: @ChristopherOrr I'm not asking it to print that - that I can figure out pretty sure on my own. I'm asking it to print what it adds in front of the path.

Comment: @wvxw You wrote "Why can't it print what path it didn't find?" which is what I answered? The only thing "added" in front of the path when archiving artifacts is the workspace directory, which is printed at the start of the console output.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr no, apparently, it isn't, because if that was the case, it would have worked. Also, think again about what I'm saying and your response: Jenkins doesn't fail to open an unexpanded path - there's no such thing as opening an unexpanded path. It fails at some concrete file name - this is the one I want to know, and this is the one it should tell me. Telling me the path before expansion (or rather an arbitrary chunk of it) is utterly useless.

Comment: @wxvw Then I guess I'm completely lost by the mixed terms and lack of context in the question and in your comments. But hopefully the answer works out anyway.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr If by mixed you meant "unfamiliar", then path expansion means substitution of special characters with actual path parts, which are deduced from the actual file system. I.e. On MS Windows this is commonly only `*`, `?` and evn. variables like `%HOME%`, but standard Unix shell can do more. However, you cannot query file system before you make this substitution. Thus, the query may only fail at a concrete file name, which has no asterisks. Hence, contrary to what you suggested, the program has a concrete path, which failed. There is no ambiguity involved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to archive individual artifacts (i.e. files).

To archive all files (including all subdirectories) in the `sdk/deploy/integration` directory, enter `sdk/deploy/integration/**`.

To archive *only* the files in the `integration` directory itself, enter `sdk/deploy/integration/*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will be around the server tomorrow morning, and will see if that was the problem. However, given this will work, I'd have two questions: is there a way to use another archive? Zip is really the wrong archiver to use, when compressing many text files. 2. Is there a way to affect the archive structure - having all of the files in the archive in the topmost directory is a bad idea - people tend to extract the content into the same directory with the archive - this will scatter many files around it - not a nice experience...

Comment: Zip is the only option provided. The directory structure of the archived files is preserved.